# Es posible recibir varias consultas desde sql con rest spring boot?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, rest

ejemplo
implemente un servicio rest en spring boot que
consume un procedimiento almacenado que muestra lo que se ve en la imagen adjunta pero al ejecutarlo en localhost
con sus respectivos parametros solo muestra el primer conjunto de resultados, ¿es posible crear ese servicio pero que muestre todas las consultas del procedimiento en un mismo json?

gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]